# Update the DE using Ampscript from Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I've developed a landing page with two submit buttons, CTA1 and CTA2. When a user clicks on CTA1, data should be updated/inserted into DE1. Similarly, clicking on CTA2 should update/insert data into DE1, but with a different row for each button. Both rows should have the same user, but with different CTA_Button values. I've set up two primary keys, II and CTA_Button. However, after the first submission, users encounter a '500 Internal server error' when attempting to resubmit the button value. Could you please assist with this issue?

```
%%[
 var @subscriberKey, @value, @email
  SET @subscriberKey = _subscriberkey 
  
  IF RequestParameter("submitted") == "true" THEN
        /* Retrieve form data */
        SET @value = RequestParameter("value")
        SET @identity_identifier = @subscriberKey /* Get Subscriber Key */
        SET @email = emailaddr /* Get Subscriber Email */
        SET @createdDate = Now()  /* Get current date and time */
        
        /* Lookup to check if the user exists in the Data Extension */
        SET @lookupRows = LookupRows('AT_Unsubcribe_Data', 'identity_identifier', @identity_identifier, 'CTA_Button', @value)
        SET @rowCount = RowCount(@lookupRows)
        
        IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
        /* User exists Update existing row with CTA1 value */
                Upsertdata('AT_Unsubcribe_Data', 1, 'identity_identifier', @identity_identifier, 'Email_Address', emailaddr, 'CTA_Button', @value, 'CreatedDate', @createdDate) 
        ELSE
        /* User doesn't exist, insert a new row */
        InsertData('AT_Unsubcribe_Data', 'identity_identifier', @identity_identifier, 'Email_Address', emailaddr, 'CTA_Button', @value, 'CreatedDate', @createdDate)
     ENDIF
     ]%%
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://at.iqos.com/de/">
    %%[
    ENDIF
    ]%%

%%[
 IF RequestParameter("unsub") == "true" THEN
 
  /* Retrieve form data */
        SET @value = RequestParameter("value")
        SET @identity_identifier = @subscriberKey /* Get Subscriber Key */
        SET @email = emailaddr /* Get Subscriber Email */
        SET @createdDate = Now()  /* Get current date and time */
        
         /* Lookup to check if the user exists in the Data Extension */
        SET @lookupRows = LookupRows('AT_Unsubcribe_Data', 'identity_identifier', @identity_identifier, 'CTA_Button', @value)
        SET @rowCount = RowCount(@lookupRows)
        
         IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
        /* User exists Update existing row with CTA1 value */
                Upsertdata('AT_Unsubcribe_Data', 1, 'identity_identifier', @identity_identifier, 'Email_Address', emailaddr, 'CTA_Button', @value, 'CreatedDate', @createdDate) 
        ELSE
        /* User doesn't exist, insert a new row */
        InsertData('AT_Unsubcribe_Data', 'identity_identifier', @identity_identifier, 'Email_Address', emailaddr, 'CTA_Button', @value, 'CreatedDate', @createdDate)
    ENDIF
    
 ////UNSUB CODE////

 ENDIF
]%%
    <!-- CTA Button 1 -->
<div class="container">
      
      <div align="center">
    <form method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="value" value="Weiterhin_E_Mails_erhalten">
   
      <button type="submit" class="submit_btn btn " style="background-color:#34303D;border:1px solid #34303D;border-radius:45px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family: ‘IQOS’, Noto Sans, sans-serif; font-weight:normal;line-height:30px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:280px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;font-size:16px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; cursor: pointer;">Weiterhin E-Mails erhalten:CTA1</button>
    </form>

  </div></div>
  
<div class="container">     
      
   <div style="padding-top: 30px;"></div>
  
    <div align="center">
       <form method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="unsub" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="value" value="Jetzt_abmelden">
    <button type="submit" class="submit_btn btn " style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #34303D;border-radius:45px;color:#34303D;display:inline-block;font-family: ‘IQOS’, Noto Sans, sans-serif; font-weight:normal;line-height:30px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:280px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;font-size:16px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; cursor: pointer;">Jetzt abmelden:CTA2</button>
    </form>         
      </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: if this: `////UNSUB CODE////` is part of your AMPscript code, it must fail at some point. That's a javascript comment, AMPscript only allows `/**/` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your script only errors when resubmitting, it makes me think the issue is related to the UpsertData() function.

Are 'identity_identifier' and 'CTA_Button' both primary keys in your data extension?

You write you want to add a different row for each button, which means you should be able to exist in the DE more than once with the same subscriberkey, i.e., all combinations of 'identity_identifier' and 'CTA_Button'.

Alternatively, if this is not the problem try to take out the upsert function, and see if you still get the error.